# How do you prevent the navigation bar from hiding during scroll on mobile-safari?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

I am trying to add a link to the bottom of a webpage. In mobile-safari, after scrolling down the page the navigation bar hides, the link at the bottom of the screen ends up in the 44px void. Any touch event in that area only activates the navigation bar and slides the desired link up 44px. At this point the link can be touched. Since this seems like a UI nightmare, and I don't want to add a 44px tall space below the link because it looks strange, it would seem the best solution would be to force the navigation bar to not hide. I can live with the nav bar being on all the time.

Comment: Look up Sticky footer - it might be a useful idea

Comment: Sticky footer is what lead me to this issue. Since the suggested touch size is 44px the menu link will fall perfectly into the void (on scroll anyway). On initial load of a webpage the nav bar is active and the sticky footer is usable because it is directly on top.

Comment: could you post your current markup?

Comment: I also would very much like to know if this is possible as the new navbar minimization on scroll is causing problems for me.

Comment: Was there ever a resolution to this question?